# How to restore the down arrow icon on the Downloads folder in the home directory?

Tags: nautilus, icons, downloads

I removed the original Downloads folder in the home directory and created a new one with the same name, but the down arrow icon on the new Download folder now disappeared. Could someone please tell me how to restore that icon?
[image]

In addition, from the image above we see "Downloads" disappears also in "Places" category in the left panel. I think it should be there originally. If after restoring the down arrow icon, the "Downloads" is still not in "Places" category, I would also like to ask you to help me put "Downloads" back to "Places". Thank you.

PS: I am not using any theme.

Comment: This might be the straightforward answer you've been looking for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606950/19643

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To change the icon**, right click on the Downloads folder and select the Properties option. Now click on the folder icon in the properties window. It will give you an option to select a custom icon.

[image]

Navigate to `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places` and select the appropriate icon.

**To add an entry in the places menu**, you have to edit the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file.

`nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

[image]

Add the following entry and press `ctrl`+`X` to save -

`XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"`

Comment: Thank you so much. PS: I chose the 48 size and it fits well.